# Installing a new dimmer switch with screw terminals in place of old rotary dimmer

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I have an existing rotary dimmer in my dining room. It is the only light switch in that room and as far as I know only controls that light that is in that room. I want to install lutron maestro dimmer that says it is for single pole/3- way/or multi location. When I puller off the old light switch, I now have 4 wires- a white, a black, the green ground, and a pinkish (maybe it could be red?) wire. The new switch has the screw terminals. The right hand side has two screws- the top is a brass color and the bottom in black. On the left hand side is a blue screw. Then the ground wire which is simple. Where do I connect the other wires to the new switch?

Comment: Can you post photos of the old light switch showing where the wires went on it, and of the insides of all switch boxes involved in the circuit please?

Comment: ↑ including the connection labels & also your region/country.

Comment: I took a couple of pictures from my phone but it won't let me upload them. They say the pictures are too big. I'm not sure why. It is just a normal picture from my phone.

Comment: However I do have more information on how the old switch was connected to the outlet box. The old switch has a green, a black, and two red wires. One of the red wires was connected to the red/pinkish wire in the box, the green was attached to the bare copper wire in the box, and the black with the black in the box and the other red with the white in the box.

Comment: Also the white wire from the box is the one with the power. Not the red or black